# how to dynamically option the selected in html just using php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to dynamically the select option selected just using php in laravel but I'm getting this error:

> Use of undefined constant selected - assumed 'selected' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralast\resources\views\view.blade.php)

**below is my view blade**

```
<select class="form-control" name="assign_to" id="assign_to">
    <option selected disabled>Select support</option>
    @foreach($supports as $support)
    <option value="{{$support->id}}" {{($ticket->assign_by == $support->id ? selected : '')}}>{{$support->fullname}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Can you help me with this.

Comment: Use quote for `SELECTED`. PHP knows as CONSTANT. actually above error message shows how you should try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote your `string` (I mean you should quote the `selected`):

```
 <option value="{{$support->id}}" {{($ticket->assign_by == $support->id ? 'selected' : '')}}>{{$support->fullname}}</option>
```

Your laravel is understanding that you will print the value of `selected` constant (since no dollar-sign `$`, no string quotation `''` `""`) when the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check This use if & else

```
<select class="form-control" name="assign_to" id="assign_to">
    <option selected disabled>Select support</option>
    @foreach($supports as $support)
    @if($ticket->assign_by == $support->id)
    <option value="{{$support->id}}" selected>{{$support->fullname}}
    </option>
    @else
    <option value="{{$support->id}}">{{$support->fullname}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I know this method but its long than the one im trying. this will work also